# How to merge 2 list as a key value pair in TCL?

Tags: tcl

How to combine two list as a key value pair?

The number of elements in both the lists are same.
I have two lists as follows.

```
set a "1 2 3"
set b "One two three"
```

How can I combine like the following **dict['1':One,'2':two,'3':three]**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One feature of the `foreach` command that is easily overlooked is that it can loop over multiple lists. So, your task can simply be done like this:

```
foreach k $a v $b {dict set d $k $v}
puts $d
```

Result: 1 One 2 two 3 three

Comment: If the lists `a` and `b` have different lengths, is it possible to limit the `foreach` loop only till the shorter list ends?

Comment: In that case you can apply an `lrange` command to the two lists: `foreach k [lrange $a 0 [expr {[llength $b] - 1}]] v [lrange $b 0 [expr {[llength $a] - 1}]] {...}`. The lrange command doesn't mind if the end index exceeds the length of the list.